# Filter into a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '1', 
    'client_firstname' => 'Gareth', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-23,2016-11-24', 'room_id' => '2'),
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-25', 'room_id' => '4'),
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-26,2016-11-27,2016-11-28', 'room_id' => '2'),
    )
);
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '2', 
    'client_firstname' => 'James', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-25,2016-11-26,2016-11-27,2016-11-28', 'room_id' => '5')
    )
);
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '2', 
    'client_firstname' => 'Marco', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-24', 'room_id' => '5')
    )
);
```

**How can I loop into this to get items with the first item in `days[]` equal to the current date or the date I want ?**

For example, if we are the `2016-11-23`, I need to get the first item into the array which is:

```
$bookings[] = array(
    'booking_id' => '1', 
    'client_firstname' => 'Gareth', 
    'days' => array(
        array('day_id' => '2016-11-23,2016-11-24', 'room_id' => '2')
    )
);
```

because into the `days` array, it starts with the date I search `2016-11-23`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little unclear, but `array_filter` is what you want. It takes a callback function which you can use to interrogate each item in the outer array. If you return something trueish from this function, the array item is included in the filtered array. If you return something falseish, the array item is excluded from the filtered array.

Rough example below, based on what I think you're asking for. If it's wrong, it should give you the right idea to tweak it.

```
<?php
$filtered = array_filter($bookings, function($item) {
        $days = explode(',', $item['days'][0]['day_id']);

        return $days[0] == '2016-11-23';
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

I suggest you also add some sanity checking to this to avoid errors in the event of bad data.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the booking array matching the date you provide

```
<?php
    $day_value = '2016-11-23';
    $bookings_ = array();
    foreach($bookings as $b){
        foreach($b['days'] as $day){
           if(in_array($day_value,explode(',',$day['day_id']))){
             $bookings_[]  = $b;
           }
        }
    }
    var_dump($bookings_);
```

Comment: Hum I get all the dates actually with your code. I need to get only the `days[]` lines beginning by the current date. I think we're need here.

Comment: And if I use the `2016-11-25`, it should return me two bookings (ids 1 and 2).

Comment: It's the same. I need to get the `days[]` info into my new array `only` if the first day of this array is the day I'm looking for. Actually, it's if the day is in the array, not the first one. Thanks.